# Storing a large object into PostgreSQL, with a high refreshing rate requirement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a big JSON which is representing the state of a Kubernetes cluster. I would like to store it in PostgreSQL, especially the list of all pods with their specs.

It would be something like that, but with more fields :

```
{
    "pods": [

        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "app",
                "namespace": "production"
            },
            "labels": {
                "something": "something"
            },
            "annotations": {
                "something": "something"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [{
                    "name": "my-container",
                    "containerPorts": [{
                        "name": "http",
                        "containerPort": 80
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Although, I'm not sure if I should :

1. Create a schema to represent all that (and it would mean several tables, since pods contain containers, ports, etc),
2. Use one table, with a JSON field storing the whole thing (and then make queries on that).

Note that I don't need all the fields. I could rework that JSON before insertion.

More-over, I want to refresh that state every 10 seconds, so if it was a complex schema with several tables, it would mean a lot of cleanup / upserts etc.

I feel like the JSON solution would be more appropriate, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Option 1 usually works better in a relational database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: Even with a lot of insert / update / delete ? Kubernetes can hold a lof of pods. I have no idea how to measure the impact on the database.

Comment: And databases can hold a lot of information, it's what they are designed to do. And if you design your schema correctly you will eliminate replication of data and only work on the parts that change. Using tables will also help in making retrieval easier then what is essentially walking through a nested database if you use JSON. If SQL is not your thing then don't use a SQL database, use a NoSQL data store instead.

Comment: We have a database processing 20 to 50 million records daily, each record within milliseconds. Most of the time this database is just waiting for new data.